# Setting up alias for specific folder for specific command

Tags: command-line, alias

I have an CLI app which works by navigating to the dir using `cd` and then executing program `2fa, code`

The problem is that those commands works only if Im on that specific folder.
How I can make a alias which will be widely understood?
So I can 2fa everywhere, even I'm on `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use full paths. Instead of `2fa`, use `$HOME/dir/2fa`.